# Does Apex class test coverage of NaN% effect my overall org test coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I just ran into everyone's favourite deployment error message:

> Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 74%, at least 75% test coverage is required.

When investigating test coverage of various Apex classes, I noticed that some have a coverage value of `NaN%` as shown below:

```
01p8E000002HmFgQAK  MyVeryImportantService           93%      26   
01p8E000002RyphQAC  OpportunityStageNames            NaN%
```

The Apex class `OpportunityStageNames` just contains `public static final String` properties:

```
public class OpportunityStageNames {
    public static final String Qualification = 'Qualification';
    ...
    public static final String ClosedLost = 'Closed\Lost';
    public static final String ClosedWon = 'Closed\Won';
}
```

To avoid having any `magic strings` in the code base.

My question is, does Apex class test coverage of NaN% effect my overall org test coverage in a negative way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.

Apex test coverage is calculated as the percentage of lines covered out of total executable lines.

The class `OpportunityStageNames` contains no executable lines of code, so it cannot be covered, and its lines do not contribute to the denominator of the fraction `(lines covered)/(total executable lines)` across any defined subset of your Apex code or the total corpus.

Comment: Note: this is a bug with the DX CLI. I've reported this so it can be fixed at some point. Regardless, this answer is perfectly correct.